# Ansible - msg: No package matching '$item' is available

Tags: ansible

I need to set-up my server. I've the following ansible playbook.

```
---

- hosts: webservers
  user: root
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: add nginx ppa
      action: apt_repository repo=ppa:nginx/stable state=present

    - name: install common packages needed for python application development
      action: apt pkg=$item state=installed
      with_items:
        - libpq-dev
        - libmysqlclient-dev
        - libxml2-dev
        - libxslt1-dev
        - mysql-client
        - python-dev
        - python-setuptools
        - python-mysqldb
        - build-essential
        - git
        - nginx

    - name: install pip
      action: easy_install name=pip

    - name: install various libraries with pip
      action: pip name=$item state=present
      with_items:
        - uwsgi

  handlers:
    - name: restart nginx
      service: name=nginx state=restarted
```

When I run this script, following is the output

```
PLAY [webservers] ************************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [IP]

TASK: [add nginx ppa] ********************************************************* 
ok: [IP]

TASK: [install common packages needed for python application development] ***** 
failed: [IP] => (item=libpq-dev,libmysqlclient-dev,libxml2-dev,libxslt1-dev,mysql-client,python-dev,python-setuptools,python-mysqldb,build-essential,git,nginx) => {"failed": true, "item": "libpq-dev,libmysqlclient-dev,libxml2-dev,libxslt1-dev,mysql-client,python-dev,python-setuptools,python-mysqldb,build-essential,git,nginx"}
msg: No package matching '$item' is available

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/praful/setup_server.yaml.retry

IP              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I've referred [this](http://mattupstate.com/python/devops/2012/08/07/flask-wsgi-application-deployment-with-ubuntu-ansible-nginx-supervisor-and-uwsgi.html) link for the same.

I'm new to ansible and dont understand the error, since there is no typo in the package name provided in `with_items`. **What exactly is the error??**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the jinja variable syntax `{{item}}` where you have `$item`.